# Trying to get full path of a chosen file by button from filedialog in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, filepath

Typing a GUI for further merging it with another part of code. I have stuck with getting full path of a file like "x:/folder1/folder2/Sample.rar" as a string. I need it to place into a Label or Entry (whatever, just to show it fetched) and using this string for further input that will do some work.
I have tried to get is as a str but didn't get any result.
Looking forward to learn a way to make a string.

```
import os
#import rarfile
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from cgitb import text

window = Tk()
window.title("GUI")
window.geometry('430x500')

lbl3 = Label(window, text="Choose log archives: ", font='Trebushet 8')
lbl3.grid(column=0, row=10)

browseFile = Button(text="Browse files", font='Trebushet 8', width=15, command=lambda : 
            filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
            title = "Seledct archives including logs",
            filetypes = (("RAR files","*.rar"))))
browseFile.grid(column=0, row=11)

FileName = Label(window)
FileName.grid(column=0, row=12)

if browseFile:
    print (str(FileName))
window.mainloop()
```

> **Copy comment**:I have found an approach but Label is not callable.
>
> ```
> def print_path(): 
>     f = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename( parent=window, initialdir='C:/', title='Choose file', filetypes=[("RAR files","*.rar"), ("all files","*.*")] ) print(str(FileName())) 
>     browseFile = tkinter.Button(window, text='Browse file', 
>                                 command=print_path) 
>     browseFile.grid(column=0, row=11) 
>     browseFile.pack(fill=FileName())
> ```

Comment: How, do you think `.askopenfilename(...` returns the selected file name? Read [tutorial - dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs)

Comment: I have found an approach but Label is not callable.

`def print_path():
    f = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
        parent=window, initialdir='C:/',
        title='Choose file',
        filetypes=[("RAR files","*.rar"),
                   ("all files","*.*")]
        )
 
    print(str(FileName()))
 
browseFile = tkinter.Button(window, text='Browse file', command=print_path)
browseFile.grid(column=0, row=11)
browseFile.pack(fill=FileName())`

Comment: With applying all the points, I will reply then with working code. Thanks for the link, sir

Comment: The solution is found. Appreciate for the reference. Label is not a way to place a Str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my dear friends. I have defined a solution that meet my requirements. It's a simple definition of entry and using Entry as a convenient way to insert str.

```
def input():
input_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Open file",
             filetypes=[("RAR files","*.rar"), ("all files","*.*")]
)

print(input_path)
input_entry.delete(1, END)  # Remove current text in entry
input_entry.insert(0, input_path)  # Insert the 'path'

button = Button(window, text='Choose a file', command=lambda : input())
button.grid(column=0, row=11)

Empty4 = Label(window)
Empty4.grid(column=0, row=12)

input_entry = Entry(window, text="")
input_entry.grid(column=0, row=13)
input_entry.focus_set()
input_entry.update()
```

My thankfulness for the ideas and hints that you dropped in here.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a , to the filetypes arg, see below.

filetypes = (("RAR files","*.rar"),)))

Comment: It's definitely much better not, sir. Appreciate